# Navigator Trouble

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Good afternoon, actually i m keeping error while try to navigate.

This is my App.js

```
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Login from './src/Login';
import NuovoAccount from './src/NuovoAccount';
import HomePage from './src/HomePage';
import Lista_Sveglie from './src/Lista_Sveglie';
import NuovoAccount_2 from './src/NuovoAccount_2';
import Nuova_sveglia from './src/Nuova_sveglia';
import ScreenSveglia from './src/ScreenSveglia';
import Registra from './src/Registra';
import temp from './src/temp';
import Account from './src/Menu/Account';
import ElencoUtenti from './src/Menu/ElencoUtenti';
import MenuImpostazioni from './src/Menu/MenuImpostazioni';
import SelUtenteDest from './src/Menu/SelUtenteDest'
import Accedi from './src/Accedi'
import Landing from './Landing'

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: Landing,
    Accedi : Accedi ,
    Login: Login,
    NuovoAccount: NuovoAccount,
    HomePage: HomePage,
    Lista_Sveglie: Lista_Sveglie,
    NuovoAccount_2: NuovoAccount_2,
    Nuova_sveglia: Nuova_sveglia,
    ScreenSveglia: ScreenSveglia,
    Registra: Registra,
    temp: temp,
    MenuImpostazioni: MenuImpostazioni,
    ElencoUtenti: ElencoUtenti,
    Account: Account,
    SelUtenteDest: SelUtenteDest,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",

    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerTintColor: '#ccc',
      headerStyle: {
        borderBottomWidth: 4,
        borderBottomColor: '#80ba27',
        backgroundColor: '#364054',

      },
      headerTitleStyle: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        flex: 1
      },


    }
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator)
```

and here my Landing.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import HomePage from './src/HomePage';
import Accedi from './src/Accedi'
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

export default class Landing extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            loggedIn: false,
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        console.log("QUI ENTRA")
     ---some firebase config ...

        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({ loggedIn: true })
            } else {
                this.setState({ loggedIn: false })
            }
        })

    }

    render(){
            if (this.state.loggedIn){
                return <HomePage/>
            }else{
                return <Accedi/>
            }
    }
}
```

Here my HomePage

```
<View>
    <Text
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('MenuImpostazioni')}
    style={style.footer_text_icone}>Configura Impostazioni</Text>
</View>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix it and explain why this error ?
from documentation i saw this.props. is created on createnavigator function

"undefined is not an object - this.prop.navigation.navigate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your `HomePage` component isn't a direct child of your stackNavigator. You need to pass it trough props to your child component doing:

```
  render(){
      if (this.state.loggedIn){
          return <HomePage navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
      }else{
          return <Accedi/>
      }
}
```

Inside the render function of your Landing.js

Then your child component will have access to it.

This is happening because you are using the same component, both as screen that as child component.

```
{
    Home: Landing,                  //Here (as child)
    Accedi : Accedi ,
    Login: Login,
    NuovoAccount: NuovoAccount,
    HomePage: HomePage,             //Here
    Lista_Sveglie: Lista_Sveglie,
    NuovoAccount_2: NuovoAccount_2,
    Nuova_sveglia: Nuova_sveglia,
    ScreenSveglia: ScreenSveglia,
    Registra: Registra,
    temp: temp,
    MenuImpostazioni: MenuImpostazioni,
    ElencoUtenti: ElencoUtenti,
    Account: Account,
    SelUtenteDest: SelUtenteDest,
}
```

`react-navigation` doesn't give access to navigation to a component just because it has been declared inside of it. By doing that if/else you are actually creating a whole new instance of that same component, with the only difference that it do not have access to `this.props.navigation`.

Comment: Thanks ! Navigation work ! but still trouble in header of this 2 pages.
```
static navigationOptions = () => {
 return {
  title: 'Centrale',
  headerRight: <View />,
        };
    };
```

Comment: Vedo che sei di Roma , è possibile avere una mail per contattarti ? Grazie @Auticcat

Answer (score 0):

`Landing.js` isn't a screen that is defined within your stack navigator, so it does not have access to `this.props.navigation`.

If you don't want `Landing.js` within the stack navigator, you can follow this tutorial to use `navigate` and other navigation actions from any component: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html